# Best way of declaring global variables?

Tags: c++, global, declaration, definition

I have an OpenGL application which requires the use of a vector in more than one OpenGL function. As far as I know the best way of dealing with this is to declare the vector in a header file, and include the header file in all the files containing the OpenGL functions.

The problem is that I get a multiple definition error at the linker stage. What is the best solution to this? Is there a better way of doing it without globals?

Comment: Learn the difference between definition and declaration. Declare the vector in a header file. Define the vector in a single source file.

Comment: I doubt you actually need a global. What's wrong with passing it around as argument?

Comment: delnan, you cannot pass your own arguments into OpenGL functions!

Comment: This is because they are pre-defined callbacks.

Comment: What do you mean by OpenGL function then? As far as I know, OpenGL defines no callbacks. Are you talking about GLSL shaders? There's `uniform` for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Define** your vector in one of the implementation files and **declare** it as `extern` in rest of the places where it's needed or in header file.

In most cases globals are not the way to go, but without having a look at the overall design no one can tell for sure what's the best for your situation.

Comment: Okay thanks, how do I go about doing this? After the header file containing my class, do I declare a vector of classes with the extern keyword?

Comment: Yes. And make sure to make a **single** definition in one of the implementation files

Answer (score -3):

the other way is to use Singleton pattern

Comment: I got commented by @JonSkeet for suggesting that... And not with a positive message...

Comment: @ppeterka I'd be fairly sure he'd more politely than I.